# How to perform a K-fold cross validation and understanding the outputs

Tags: r, validation, regression, cross-validation

I have been trying to perform  k-fold cross-validation in R on a data set that I have created. The link to this data is as follows:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6vqHScIRbB-S0ZYZW1Ga0VMMjA

I used the following code:

```
    library(DAAG)
    six = read.csv("six.csv") #opening file

    fit <- lm(Height ~ GLCM.135 + Blue + NIR, data=six) #applying a regression model
    summary(fit) # show results

    CVlm(data =six, m=10, form.lm = formula(Height ~  GLCM.135 + Blue + NIR )) # 10 fold cross validation
```

This produces the following output (Summarized version)

```
    Sum of squares = 7.37    Mean square = 1.47    n = 5 

    Overall (Sum over all 5 folds) 
    ms 
    3.75 

    Warning message:

    In CVlm(data = six, m = 10, form.lm = formula(Height ~ GLCM.135 +  : 

    As there is >1 explanatory variable, cross-validation
    predicted values for a fold are not a linear function
    of corresponding overall predicted values.  Lines that
    are shown for the different folds are approximate
```

I do not understand what the **ms** value refers to as I have seen different interpretations on the internet. It is my understanding that K-fold cross validations produce a overall RMSE value for a specified model (which is what I am trying to obtain for my research).

I also don't understand why the results generated produce a **Overall (Sum over all 5 folds)**, when I have specified a 10 fold cross validation in the code.

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ran this same thing, I saw that it did do 10 folds, but the final output printed was the same as yours ("Sum over all 5 folds").  The "ms" is the mean squared prediction error.  The value of 3.75 is not exactly a simple average across all 10 folds either (got 3.67):

```
msaverage <- (1.19+6.04+1.26+2.37+3.57+5.24+8.92+2.03+4.62+1.47)/10
msaverage
```

Notice the average as well as most folds are higher than "Residual standard error" (1.814).  This is what we would expect as the CV error represents model performance likely on "test" data (not data used to trained the model).  For instance on Fold 10, notice the residuals calculated are on the predicted observations (5 observations) that were not used in the training for that model:

```
fold 10 
Observations in test set: 5 
           12    14     26    54    56
Predicted   20.24 21.18 22.961 18.63 17.81
cvpred      20.15 21.14 22.964 18.66 17.86
Height      21.98 22.32 22.870 17.12 17.37
CV residual  1.83  1.18 -0.094 -1.54 -0.49

Sum of squares = 7.37    Mean square = 1.47    n = 5
```

It appears this warning we received may be common too -- also saw it in this article:  http://www.rpubs.com/jmcimula/xCL1aXpM3bZ

One thing I can suggest that may be useful to you is that in the case of linear regression, there is a closed form solution for leave-one-out-cross-validation (loocv) without actually fitting multiple models.

```
predictedresiduals <- residuals(fit)/(1 - lm.influence(fit)$hat)
PRESS <- sum(predictedresiduals^2)
PRESS  #Predicted Residual Sum of Squares Error
fitanova <- anova(fit)  #Anova to get total sum of squares
tss <- sum(fitanova$"Sum Sq")   #Total sum of squares
predrsquared <- 1 - PRESS/(tss)
predrsquared
```

Notice this value is 0.574 vs. the original Rsquared of 0.6422

To better convey the concept of RMSE, it is useful to see the distribution of the predicted residuals:

```
hist(predictedresiduals)
```

RMSE can then calculated simply as:

```
sd(predictedresiduals)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, My stats aren't the greatest, is there any way that one can obtain a RMSE value from the method you suggested. if not how can I interpret this new method you have proposed as i need to validate this model in form.

Comment: RMSE from the original LM can be obtained by 'summary(fit)$sigma'. It can also be calculated on PRESS as 'RMSE <- sqrt(PRESS/57)'. Note that this value is slightly higher in accordance with the fact that it is calculated on the predicted residuals (from the loocv); is more likely to what you can expect from model performance on new data.  An even easier way to think about RMSE is just the standard deviation of the residuals.  I'll add this above...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Just to confirm the RMSE refers to the difference between the predicted Height value and the actual height value as determined by the model

Comment: The difference between the predicted and actuals are called residuals.  The RMSE is the standard deviation of the residuals

Comment: Thank you have been of great help